# How to load stylesheets in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, styles

In my rails 3 application I have added the stylesheets in

```
  /app/assets/stylesheets/   instead of /public/stylesheets
```

but the stylesheets files are not loaded when I specified the path as

```
  <link href="/app/assets/stylesheets/home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Do I need to configure something to load this stylesheets

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3.1, Rails uses the so-called asset pipeline to load assets for you, including CSS. So the idea isn't to just move stylesheets, etc. to another folder, but to put them there and have them assembled/compiled by the framework.

Specifically, to get your setup working, you'll need to use several gems required by the assets pipeline (Sprockets in particular).

If you're upgrading to Rails 3.1 from an earlier version, I found these 2 articles helpful: http://ridingrails.net/updating-rails-31/ http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1?view=asciicast

If you've created a Rails 3.1 application from scratch, you shouldn't need to do anything: application.css already requires all the files in the app/assets/stylesheets directory with the `= require_tree .` command, and the `application` stylesheet should already be included in the layout.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the link like this to reference your stylesheets, rather use the `stylesheet_link_tag` ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/StylesheetTagHelpers.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag%20doc)) ActionView method to get these in. The asset pipeline will actually end up having the URL be somewhat different from what you do.

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your application.css should be following:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

This will include all css files from `/app/assets/stylesheets/`.

Comment: Might not be what the poster wants, though. I personally don't like this way as I have controller-specific stylesheets.

Comment: How would you do that Romain? Loading controller-specific stylesheets.